# Search into MySQL PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have JSON 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' from where I take data and populate MySQL. Then I connect to MySQL and display data. I made a search box and button to serch inside my table and it works perfectly. The result I display it in table in mt php page. But i have one problem. This is how I insert JSON data into MySQL and here is the table where I display data from DB in to my php page:

```
     function getDati()
        {
            $url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';
            $cURL = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Accept: application/json'
            ));

            $result = curl_exec($cURL);
            curl_close($cURL);
            $all_items = json_decode($result);
            return $all_items;
        }
    //DB CONECTION
    class Database
    {
        private $db_host;
        private $db_name;
        private $db_username;
        private $db_password;

        public function dbConnection()
        {
            $this->db_host = 'localhost';
            $this->db_name = 'items';
            $this->db_username = '*****';
            $this->db_password = '****';
            try {
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->db_host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name, $this->db_username, $this->db_password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $conn;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Connection error " . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
//connecto to DB to displayit into my php page
<?php
            $database = new Database;
            $db = $database->dbConnection();
            $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts ");
            $stmt->execute();
            ?>
 <table class="table table-hover">
                    <hr>
                    <div style="text-align: center"> <label class="badge badge-light" style="font-size:30px; background-color: #2196F3;">All Items</label></div>
                    <hr>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>User ID</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Compiled</th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php foreach ($stmt as $item) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $item['userId'] ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $item['id'] ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $item['title'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $item['completed'] ? 'Compiled' : 'Not Compiled' ?></td> //completed is boolean so I used "? 'Compiled' : 'Not Compiled'" to not be displayed 0 or 1 
</tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </table>
```

And here is HTML code for search box and button:

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
            <input name="search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button name="submit-search" class="btn  my-2 my-sm-0 bg-white" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
```

And code for  function Search():

```
function search()
{
    $keyword = '%' . $_POST['search'] . '%';
    $database = new Database;
    $db = $database->dbConnection();
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id LIKE '$keyword' OR userId LIKE '$keyword' OR title LIKE '$keyword'  OR completed LIKE  '$keyword'");
    $stmt->execute();
 <div class="container" style=" margin-top:5%;">
        <table class=" table table-hover" id="search-table" style="font-size: 18px;">
            <hr>
            <div style="text-align:center;"> <label style="text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); font-size:30px;border-radius: 45px; "> Results from search : </label></div> <br>
            <tr>
                <th>User ID:</th>
                <th> ID: </th>
                <th> Title: </th>
                <th> Compiled: </th>
            </tr>

            <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['userId'] ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['id'] ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['title'] ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['completed'] ? 'Compiled' : 'Not Compiled' ?> </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile ?>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that JSON file have one array with 200 objects and those 200 objects have properties like *userId, id, title, completed*. **Completed** is boolean type and inside MySQL it is saved like 0 or 1 (false / true). So obviously when I type *Completed or Not completed* in my search box it results nothing.

How can I display all Completed or Not completed items that are  in my MySQL table when I type *Completed* or *Not completed* in the search box.

**UPDATE:**
My HTML search from 2 inputs :

```
<div class="container bg-light " style=" margin-top:8%; width:30%;" id="searcform">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="text-center">
            <label class="h3 font-weight-bold">SEARCH BY:</label>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">User ID: </label>
            <input type="text" name="userId" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="search-btn2" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        <hr>
    </form>
</div>
```

And PHP search from 2 inputs :

```
if (isset($_POST['search-btn2'])) {

    $values = [];
    $conditions = [];
    $conditions[] = "1";  /* trivial condition that is True */

    $userId = $_POST['userId'];
    if ($userId != '') {
        $values[] = $userId;
        $conditions[] = "userId = ?";
    }
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    if ($title  != '') {
        $values[] = $title;
        $conditions[] = "title like concat('%', ?, '%')";
    }

    $database = new Database;
    $db = $database->dbConnection();
    $cond = join(' AND ', $conditions);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE $cond";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($values);
}
?>
```

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. For example: if the search string would contain a single quote or end with a backslash, your query query woud fail.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson 
Yes I know, but that is not a problem in this case.

Comment: $completedTest = $_POST['search'] == 'Completed';

Comment: @RiggsFolly Where to put that?

Comment: Also `$stmt = $db->query("SELECT *, IF(completed=1,'Completed','Not Completed') as completed FROM posts WHERE id LIKE '$keyword' OR userId LIKE '$keyword' OR title LIKE '$keyword'  OR completed LIKE  '$keyword'");` is not working

Comment: before using it in the query where clause

Comment: Your Database Class is going to generate lots of connections and very soon you will run out of them, they are a finite resource

Comment: `$completedTest = $_POST['search'] == 'Completed';` Seems like it works only for Completed. The result is mixed up with some _Not Compiled_ records

Comment: You may need to take that whole `completed LIKE  '$keyword'` out of the query unless the thing being queried contains either `Completed` or `Not completed`

Comment: I tried it's not working

Comment: `$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id LIKE '$keyword' OR userId LIKE '$keyword' OR title LIKE '$keyword'  OR (completed = if('not completed' Like 'not completed', 0, null) OR completed = if('completed' LIKE 'Completed', 1, null))");` 
This works but the result is all rows from MySQL table because all row are or Completed or Not Completed which is also logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that your search box contain a separate input widget for each parameter the user can supply.

You should use a `<select>` HTML tag for specifying the `completed` search parameter as follows:

```
<select name="completed">
    <option value=''>-- Select a Completion Value --</option>
    <option value="0">Not Completed</option>
    <option value="1">Completed</option>
</select>
```

You could have a `<select>` tag for the `id` parameter:

```
<select name="id">
    <option value=''>-- Select an id value --</option>
    <option value="id-value-1">id-value-1</option>
    <option value="id-value-2">id-value-2</option>
    . . .
    <option value="id-value-N">id-value-N</option>
</select>
```

The above would have to be initialized in a loop. Or else you could have a simple text box where the user has to type in the id of the row of interest.

You should have text input fields userId and title:

```
User Id: <input type="text" name="userId">
Title: <input type="text" name="title">
```

Your PHP code then should be:

```
$values = [];
$conditions = [];
$conditions[] = "1";
$completed = $_POST['completed'];
if ($completed != '') {
    $values[] = $completed;
    $conditions[] = "completed = ?";
}
$id = $_POST['id'];
if ($id != '') {
    $values[] = $id;
    $conditions[] = "id = ?";
}
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
if ($userId != '') {
    $values[] = $userId;
    $conditions[] = "userId = ?";
}
$title = $_POST['title'];
if ($title  != '') {
    $values[] = $title;
    $conditions[] = "title like concat('%', ?, '%')";
}
$cond = join(' AND ', $conditions);
$db = $database->dbConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE $cond");
$stmt->execute($values);
```

Note that the above code used a prepared statement to prevent SQL Injection attacks. If you can ensure that there is always at least one input criteria specified such that the `$conditions` array is not empty, then the `1` condition can be removed from the SELECT statement.

Comment: I shold change my  `function search()` to code that you post **Your PHP code then should be:....**  ?

Comment: Yes, if you make the change to the search box as I suggest or use it as a guideline. I was trying to make two points: (1) The use of a prepared statement. (2) A different user interface that is easier for the user to understand and use.

Comment: Can you help me with PHP code?  I made 2 inputs _userId_ and _title_ . It gaves me error **Undefined index: title** and **Undefined index: userId** and **Syntax error or access violation:...**

Comment: Your `<form method="post">` tag *contains* an `<input name="userId">` tag and you are saying that `$_POST['userId']` results in an **Undefined index: userId** error? You may need to post the HTML and code as a separate question.

Comment: I update my question with new code for 2 Inputs and PHP code

Comment: You did *not* follow my code. You are mixing `?` SQL parameters with `:X` type parameters. I have edited your question to put back the code the way it should be.